# How to make background dim when you press your modal button with react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem when I press my modal button, it just shows the modal but the background is not dim.

The example that I want is here
[image: Example]

```
This is my code  JS
[JS][2]https://pastebin.com/04AG1Y0f

and my CSS 
[CSS][3]https://pastebin.com/04AG1Y0f
```

How to make it like the image

Comment: Add a code snippet to your question instead of links and images

Comment: create a small demo https://jsfiddle.net/ instead of pastebin links.

Comment: @Solonik, better option is to create the snippet *here*. Can you imagine what happens to such question when JSFiddle is down? It will probably become valueless.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, in addition to rendering a modal when you click your button, also render an empty div. Style the div such that it has a fixed position and covers the entire screen, have a gray color, and set the opacity such that it looks like in your example above. Should also set a low/negative z-value so that it doesn't appear on a layer above your modal.

Answer (score 1):

(if you are using bootstrap...)
You just need to add `data-backdrop="static"` attribute to your modal.

What you are looking for is called `modal backdrop`.

you can read more about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options).